# Delay loading of link in new background tab in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to change the behavior of "New Tabs" that are opened in Google Chrome. What I want is whenever I open a new tab in Chrome, the newly opened tab doesn't load itself until I switch to that tab.  Is there a setting to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there's no option yet that allows you to do that: I explored the `chrome://flags` section, but didn't find any option which allow you to do that, but there's a browser which allows you to do that: Opera.

You can find that setting going to the Opera settings page, then check the option "Show advanced settings" which it's at the end of the page, then back to the top of the page, check the "Continue where I left off" and then check the previously hidden option "Delay loading of background tabs".
[image: Opera's Delay loading of background tabs option]

In your next browsing sessions, the tab you are currently on will load while the other tabs will not load until you switch to them.